# Upgrading MariaDB collation from utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

Tags: unicode, mariadb

Currently I use:

- The `utf8mb4` database character set.
- The `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` database collation.

I understand that `utf8mb4` supports up to four bytes per character. I also understand that Unicode is a standard that continues to get updates. In the past I thought `utf8` was sufficient until I had some test data get corrupted, lesson learned. However I'm having difficulty understanding the upgrade path for both the character set and collations.

The `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` database collation is based off of [Unicode Collation Algorithm version 5.2.0](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/5.2.0/). If you navigate to the parent directory you'll see up to version 14.0 listed at the time of typing this. Now those are the Unicode *standards*, then there is the supported [MariaDB character sets and collations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/supported-character-sets-and-collations/).

Offhand I'm not sure when the need to go from four bytes per character gets superseded to go to eight bytes per character or even 16 so it's not as simple a measure of just updating the database collation. Additionally I'm not seeing anything that seems to be newer than version 5.2.0 on MariaDB's documentation.

So in short my three highly related questions are:

- Are the newer collations such as version 14 still fully compatible with four byte characters or have they exhausted all combinations and now require up to eight or 16 bytes per character?
- What is the latest database collation that MariaDB supports in regards to Unicode versions?
- In regards to the second question, a newer version than 5.2.0 is supported by MariaDB then is `utf8mb4` still sufficient for a character set or not?

I am not bound to or care about MySQL compatibility.

Comment: utf16 is already in use and the collations have nothing to do with 4 bytes or three or 16 for that matter

Comment: I looked through MariaDB's [JIRA bug/feature tracker](https://jira.mariadb.org) and I haven't found a request to update these. If you'd like to add this it could end up on the development roadmap. The codebase for collations is obviously extendable. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.7/strings/ctype-uca.c) it looks like a reasonable understanding of UCA and some scripting to get the constants ported will add a collation. You are [very welcome to help out](https://mariadb.org/get-involved/getting-started-for-developers/).

Comment: @danblack Thank you though I don't have the resources to do that just yet. I'm just trying to make sure I'm as up to date as possible before moving forward with something.

Comment: Just to clarify, requesting uca be updated places no obligation on you to do it. Its also the kind of task the MariaDB developers could hand out to a GSoC or university project to implement.

Comment: [MDEV-27009](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27009) for UCA14.0.0 collations is in progress.

Comment: @danblack Thank you for following up even after months! I registered and commented on the subject. I'm also really surprised that https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19123 hasn't been resolved. While I generally advocate against software wasting hardware resources that would be one instance where it would be acceptable. I'm following both threads and will update my platform once 14 presumably becomes available, thank you again Dan!

Answer (score 2):

Skipping the old 5.2.0 versions, MariaDB added UCA-14.0.0 collations in MariaDB-10.10.2 and are also available in MariaDB-10.11+ versions.

The 14.0.0 collations also include [accent insensitivity](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/supported-character-sets-and-collations/#accent-insensitivity) as an optional collation attribute.

Contractions are also supported in this version.

The list is:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS where collation_name like 'uca1400_%';
+--------------------------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
| COLLATION_NAME                 | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | ID   | IS_DEFAULT | IS_COMPILED | SORTLEN |
+--------------------------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
| uca1400_ai_ci                  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_ai_cs                  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_as_ci                  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_as_cs                  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_nopad_ai_ci            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_nopad_ai_cs            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_nopad_as_ci            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_nopad_as_cs            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_icelandic_ai_ci        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_icelandic_ai_cs        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_icelandic_as_ci        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_icelandic_as_cs        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_icelandic_nopad_ai_ci  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_icelandic_nopad_ai_cs  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_icelandic_nopad_as_ci  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_icelandic_nopad_as_cs  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_latvian_ai_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_latvian_ai_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_latvian_as_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_latvian_as_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_latvian_nopad_ai_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_latvian_nopad_ai_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_latvian_nopad_as_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_latvian_nopad_as_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_romanian_ai_ci         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_romanian_ai_cs         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_romanian_as_ci         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_romanian_as_cs         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_romanian_nopad_ai_ci   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_romanian_nopad_ai_cs   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_romanian_nopad_as_ci   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_romanian_nopad_as_cs   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovenian_ai_ci        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovenian_ai_cs        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovenian_as_ci        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovenian_as_cs        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovenian_nopad_ai_ci  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovenian_nopad_ai_cs  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovenian_nopad_as_ci  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovenian_nopad_as_cs  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_polish_ai_ci           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_polish_ai_cs           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_polish_as_ci           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_polish_as_cs           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_polish_nopad_ai_ci     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_polish_nopad_ai_cs     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_polish_nopad_as_ci     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_polish_nopad_as_cs     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_estonian_ai_ci         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_estonian_ai_cs         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_estonian_as_ci         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_estonian_as_cs         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_estonian_nopad_ai_ci   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_estonian_nopad_ai_cs   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_estonian_nopad_as_ci   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_estonian_nopad_as_cs   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish_ai_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish_ai_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish_as_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish_as_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish_nopad_ai_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish_nopad_ai_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish_nopad_as_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish_nopad_as_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_swedish_ai_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_swedish_ai_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_swedish_as_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_swedish_as_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_swedish_nopad_ai_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_swedish_nopad_ai_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_swedish_nopad_as_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_swedish_nopad_as_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_turkish_ai_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_turkish_ai_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_turkish_as_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_turkish_as_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_turkish_nopad_ai_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_turkish_nopad_ai_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_turkish_nopad_as_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_turkish_nopad_as_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_czech_ai_ci            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_czech_ai_cs            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_czech_as_ci            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_czech_as_cs            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_czech_nopad_ai_ci      | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_czech_nopad_ai_cs      | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_czech_nopad_as_ci      | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_czech_nopad_as_cs      | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_danish_ai_ci           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_danish_ai_cs           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_danish_as_ci           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_danish_as_cs           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_danish_nopad_ai_ci     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_danish_nopad_ai_cs     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_danish_nopad_as_ci     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_danish_nopad_as_cs     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_lithuanian_ai_ci       | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_lithuanian_ai_cs       | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_lithuanian_as_ci       | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_lithuanian_as_cs       | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_lithuanian_nopad_ai_ci | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_lithuanian_nopad_ai_cs | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_lithuanian_nopad_as_ci | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_lithuanian_nopad_as_cs | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovak_ai_ci           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovak_ai_cs           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovak_as_ci           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovak_as_cs           | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovak_nopad_ai_ci     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovak_nopad_ai_cs     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovak_nopad_as_ci     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_slovak_nopad_as_cs     | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish2_ai_ci         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish2_ai_cs         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish2_as_ci         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish2_as_cs         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish2_nopad_ai_ci   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish2_nopad_ai_cs   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish2_nopad_as_ci   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_spanish2_nopad_as_cs   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_roman_ai_ci            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_roman_ai_cs            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_roman_as_ci            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_roman_as_cs            | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_roman_nopad_ai_ci      | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_roman_nopad_ai_cs      | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_roman_nopad_as_ci      | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_roman_nopad_as_cs      | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_persian_ai_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_persian_ai_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_persian_as_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_persian_as_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_persian_nopad_ai_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_persian_nopad_ai_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_persian_nopad_as_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_persian_nopad_as_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_esperanto_ai_ci        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_esperanto_ai_cs        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_esperanto_as_ci        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_esperanto_as_cs        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_esperanto_nopad_ai_ci  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_esperanto_nopad_ai_cs  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_esperanto_nopad_as_ci  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_esperanto_nopad_as_cs  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_hungarian_ai_ci        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_hungarian_ai_cs        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_hungarian_as_ci        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_hungarian_as_cs        | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_hungarian_nopad_ai_ci  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_hungarian_nopad_ai_cs  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_hungarian_nopad_as_ci  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_hungarian_nopad_as_cs  | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_sinhala_ai_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_sinhala_ai_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_sinhala_as_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_sinhala_as_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_sinhala_nopad_ai_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_sinhala_nopad_ai_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_sinhala_nopad_as_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_sinhala_nopad_as_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_german2_ai_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_german2_ai_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_german2_as_ci          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_german2_as_cs          | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_german2_nopad_ai_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_german2_nopad_ai_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_german2_nopad_as_ci    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_german2_nopad_as_cs    | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_vietnamese_ai_ci       | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_vietnamese_ai_cs       | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_vietnamese_as_ci       | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_vietnamese_as_cs       | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_vietnamese_nopad_ai_ci | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_vietnamese_nopad_ai_cs | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_vietnamese_nopad_as_ci | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_vietnamese_nopad_as_cs | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_croatian_ai_ci         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_croatian_ai_cs         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_croatian_as_ci         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_croatian_as_cs         | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_croatian_nopad_ai_ci   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_croatian_nopad_ai_cs   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_croatian_nopad_as_ci   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
| uca1400_croatian_nopad_as_cs   | NULL               | NULL | NULL       | Yes         |       8 |
+--------------------------------+--------------------+------+------------+-------------+---------+
184 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

ref: [MDEV-27009](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27009)

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the collations currently supported by your MariaDB instance:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS
WHERE CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'utf8mb4';
```

As far as I know, MariaDB does not support any UTF-8 collation version more current than utf8_unicode_520ci. If you try to use the '900' version, for example importing metadata from MySQL to MariaDB, [you get errors](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/248904/mysql-to-mariadb-unknown-collation-utf8mb4-0900-ai-ci).

There is no such thing as an 8-byte or 16-byte UTF-8 encoding. UTF-8 is an encoding that uses between 1 and 4 bytes per character, no more than that.

MariaDB also supports utf16 and utf32, but neither of these uses more than 4 bytes per character. Utf16 is variable-length, using one or two 16-bit code units per character. Utf32 is fixed-width, always using 32-bits (4 bytes) per character.